# Javascript Map Tooltip Alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I recently had a developer back out on my project at the 95% completion mark and have been trying to complete this project on my own. I am currently working on the tooltip placement on the map found on this page:

https://www.shiftins.com/homeowners-insurance-california/

You can see the  source here:

https://www.shiftins.com/county/index.html

There are 2 issues I need help resolving.

1. The tooltip for the bar charts should be located at the mouse pointer; however, it is located way right of the charts
2. The tooltip for the map portion seems to disappear on the bottom right half of the counties when scaled down.

I have spent quite a few hours with the trial-and-error method trying multiple solutions but I can't seem to figure it out (especially since I am not a developer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the map tooltip to appear ,
instead of padding-left for bar char ,give left property;.
This is because ,now the bar chart is overlapping on map chart,If you keep a border you can see the overlapping  clearly.

```
 <div id="linechart" class="col-sm-3" style="width: 60%;padding-left:120px;">
```

change this line to

```
     <div id="linechart" class="col-sm-3" style="width: 60%;left:125px;">
```

For the bar tool tip to appear,
Now d3.event.pageX gives the x coordinate value of mouse.To get the accurate x value,you need to minus the offsetLeft value

```
 var x = d3.event.pageX + 5-document.getElementById("linechart").offsetLeft;
```

Comment: THANK YOU. Can you also help me move the tool tip position from to left to bottom left? OH and send me your email address.

Comment: Can you help me move the tooltip position I tried changing `d3.select("#tooltipp")
          .style("left", x + "px")
          .style("top", y + "px")` to `d3.select("#tooltipp")
          .style("left", x + "px")
          .style("bottom", y + "px")` but it did not work

Comment: I did not understand the bottom left part.You want to appear it exactly below the mouse?If that is what required , change  x to what I had mentioned above.  var x = d3.event.pageX + 5-document.getElementById("linechart").offsetLeft;

Answer (score 0):

You need to position the left and top i.e. x and y axis of the tooltip on mouseover/hover event. Something like this:

Add this style to the tooltip div:
`"left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px").style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px"`

Here is a working [example](https://bl.ocks.org/siddharthpolisiti/fce500057d7cf378cbbbb1718ea6a21c)